# I'm having problems with pygame animations

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm having some trouble with my animations in pygame, instead of it moving I only see a still image.

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

Stationary = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "stationary.png"))
left = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "L1.png")),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "L2.png")),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "L3.png")),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "L4.png"))
        ]
right = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "R1.png")),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "R2.png")),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "R3.png")),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", "R4.png"))
         ]

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
vel = 0.5
stepIndex = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
move_left = False
move_right = False
x = 50
y = 250


def draw_screen():
    global stepIndex
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    if stepIndex >= 8:
        stepIndex = 0
    if move_left:
        screen.blit(left[stepIndex//2], (x, y))
    elif move_right:
        screen.blit(right[stepIndex//2], (x, y))
    else:
        screen.blit(Stationary, (x, y))


running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    draw_screen()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
        x += vel
        move_right = True
        move_left = False
    elif keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= vel
        move_right = False
        move_left = True
    else:
        move_left = False
        move_right = False
        stepIndex = 0

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I've been staring at my code for about 2 hours now and searching across the internet for solutions and get this, I even looked at the second page of my google search just to find some answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to increment `stepIndex`:

```py
def draw_screen():
    global stepIndex
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    stepIndex += 1      # <--- this is missing
    if stepIndex >= 8:
        stepIndex = 0
    
    if move_left:
        screen.blit(left[stepIndex//2], (x, y))
    elif move_right:
        screen.blit(right[stepIndex//2], (x, y))
    else:
        screen.blit(Stationary, (x, y))
```